# Accessing document's javascript variable from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

is it possible for Firefox extension (toolbar) to access document's variables? detailed explanation follows..

loaded document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var variableForExtension = 'something';
</script>
```

extension:

```
var win = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow;
alert(win.variableForExtension); // undefined
```

it was first thing to try, and it's inaccessible this way because of security mechanisms (**XPCNativeWrapper**). i've read about accessing it trough **wrappedJSObject** and using **events** (adding listener to document and dispatching event from extension), but no luck. didn't try too hard, though. so, before i dig deeper ('events method' sounds like a way to go) i'd like to know is this even possible?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, accessing a JS variable in content is and always was possible. Doing this the naive way wasn't safe (in the sense that a malicious web page could get chrome privileges) in older Firefox versions.

1) If you control the web page and want to pass information to the extension, you should indeed use the [events technique](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets:Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages#Sending_data_from_unprivileged_document_to_chrome). This worked and was/is safe in all Firefox versions.

2) If you want to read a value from the content document, you can just bypass the XPCNativeWrapper:

```
var win = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow;
// By the way, this could just be
//   var win = content;
// or 
//   var win = gBrowser.contentWindow;
alert(win.variableForExtension); // undefined
win.wrappedJSObject.variableForExtension // voila!
```

This was unsafe prior to Firefox 3. In Firefox 3 and later it is OK to use, you get another kind of wrapper ([XPCSafeJSObjectWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers#XPCSafeJSObjectWrapper)), which looks the same as the object from the content page to your code, but ensures the content page won't be able to do anything malicious.

3) If you need to call a function in a content web page or run your own code in the page's context, it's more complicated. It was asked and answered elsewhere many times, but unfortunately never documented fully. Since this is unrelated to your question, I won't go into the details.

Comment: thanks for answering, nickolay. :) i've done the job in a bit dirty way, but will try (again) both 1 and 2 (i don't need 3, yet), now that i know it's possible.

Comment: @Nickolay. I need to deal with #3; May I ask you for pointer (it would be helpful for the community here as well). I need to read and perform actions on the content page (any web page a user may visit). You said "not documented fully but answered so many times", can you direct me to a good pointer? Digged the documentation for a few days and still couldn't get it to work. If you are curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923438/how-to-allow-addons-content-script-access-javascript-variables-from-the-current

Answer (score 4):

not so hard :)

in extension:

```
var jso=window.content.document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject;
```

now you can access any function or global variable in the webpage from the extension:

```
alert(jso.pagevar);

jso.pagefunction("hey");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the new High-Level SDKs then [accessing the variable via content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) is a little different. You can't access the JavaScript objects directly from the add on code, but you can reach them from content scripts that have been attached to an open page via the **unsafeWindow** object. For example:

```
require("sdk/tabs").open({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/some/page/',
  onOpen: function(tab) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScript: 'unsafeWindow.variableForExtension = 1000;'
    });
  }
});
```

To read the variables you'll need to use the **port** methods on the **worker** variable as described in [Mozilla's content script article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)

Note that there are some security restrictions when dealing with objects and functions. See the articles for details.