# How to communicate between content script and the panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How does the communication between a panel and a content script happen? How can we dynamically update the panel content from content script? The content script accesses the DOM of the page loaded. Now every time when there is a DOM change in the webpage that should be shown in the panel. How can we do this? Can anyone explain with an example?

UPDATE: here is [MY ADDON CODE](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1050256/revision/596/)

Please go through this code. I am not getting the output

Answer (score 8):

Your question is about communication between two content scripts - one content script loaded into a web page and another content script loaded into the panel. These content scripts cannot communicate directly, they have to communicate through the extension (`main.js` or whatever module created them). In other words: a change in the web page happens, the content script recognizes that change and sends a message to the extension. The extension receives the message and sends it to the content script in the panel. The content script in the panel then updates panel contents as necessary.

Comment: so now i should include the contentscript interacting with web page in page-mod and send the message from page-mod to panel. Is this approach appreciable

Comment: Can you provide an example which demonstrates the communication between page-mod and panel, In short sending message from page-mod to panel so that the content of panel is dynamically updated.

Comment: can you provide an example demonstrating the above explanation

Comment: Can any one please provide an example demonstrating the above given explanation

Comment: i included my code in the post please verify it. It is not working

Comment: @user1275375: "Not working" is not a problem description. Apparently you did debug it, you must have realized that the problem appears *before* you attempt to send a message. In fact, your communication code seems fine, the problem is rather that you cannot intercept `createElement` calls. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2162435/785541) explains the reason.

Comment: Thank you for replying i am not understanding what to do now. this means that i have to include `var win = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow; win.wrappedJSObject.tagName;` where should i add this in my contentScript as the `tagName` keeps on changing.