# How to allow addon's content script access Javascript variables from the current tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Supposed my add-on has to access a Javascript variable from a webpage. Let's take https://mozilla.org. There is a global variable called `optimizelyCode`. My addon will only work if this variable is accessible.

How do I let my pageMod do that?

To experiment, here are some tutorial scripts:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Mozilla website",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptWhen: 'end',
      contentScript:
        'console.log(optimizelyCode)'
        })
    }
});
```

and

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScript: 'console.log(optimizelyCode);'
});
```

I get Reference/Undefined error because `optimizelyCode` is not avaiaible to addon. In this example I am not even using content script file.

As far as I know, I can only access basic DOM stuff like `getElementById` that kind of methods. How can I access these webpage local JS variables?

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts

Comment: are you sure you're not getting that error because it's really undefined, as in, at all, or perhaps your script is running before it's defined?

Comment: Sure. I will experiment with that. I have so many scripts on hand. One moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103501/accessing-documents-javascript-variable-from-firefox-extension perhaps helpful?

Comment: @CrayonViolent please see edit. The widget has to be clicked to load the content script. The second example uses pagemod and supposely better? But same result. Okay I can take a look at that, although doesn't look very promising to me :(

Comment: @CrayonViolent I tried but couldn't get it to work (or maybe I wasn't able to reproduce it properly). The 3rd point in the answer is exactly what I am needing. I should also ping the person who answered the question. Hope someone can jump in and correct my mistakes here. *still debugging*

Comment: Which mozilla.org website have you run this on? Fo rme it works as expected, eg I get this error 'optimizelyCode is not defined' but also ( for bugzilla.mozilla.org at least ) that variable is not defined anyway

Comment: @canuckistani MDN for example. I will try the suggestions below again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is add-on SDK, it uses a different syntax from the rest of Firefox, and you need to use [`unsafeWindow.optimizelyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM#unsafeWindow).

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, from non-content-script you can do gBrowser.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.VAR_HERE